# Generating report resource usage report for child processes

Tags: resources

I'm looking for a tool that would generate a report about child processes. I'm interested in CPU usage, memory usage, etc.

Ideally the tool would be used like this:

```
uber_reporter -o report.html command -command_param_1
```

What I'm looking for on the generated report are:

- Charts over time containing CPU usage, memory usage.
- The report should contain only parent and child processes started with `command`. I.e. I'm not interested in other processes.
- The legend should contain full invocation path of the process.
- The output format is not so important, HTML was used only as example. Output format could be source for GNU plot, image, PDF, etc.

  - In the simplest form such a report could be tabularized data (e.g. CSV).

Is there any such tool existing?

The system is Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: You could create one using all *stat commands, sar, ps and pstree; Not sure if any already exists.

Comment: A wafer-thin wrapper around `getrusage(2)` in particular with `RUSAGE_CHILDREN` set for `who` might be a good starting point.